# how to write .htaccess for codeigniter version 2.2?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have done a sample project using CI2.2 . I tried many ways to remove Index.php from url. but it doesnt work. please help me to get rid of this.

My folder structre : localhost/Myproject

please help me

Comment: This as been ask so many times http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=codeigniter+remove+index.php

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Htaccess File

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it seems like you have not enabled mod_rewrite from apache change your apache config file and restart apache.

Comment: you can echo phpinfo() and check whether mod_rewrite module loaded or not under section apache2handler.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.so>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
--IfModule>                                                                                                                                                                                                                 I just changed my htaccess file like this. but it always shows error 404.